# Get custom relationship data with Eloquent query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, builder, eager-loading

I have this query :

```php
FHINotification::with(['log'])
    ->where('user', $user->getSAMAccountName())
    ->whereNull('read_at')
    ->get();
```

"Log" model has a function to get custom data (more human readable than data in db)

```php
public function getData(): array
{
    Game::setWithoutStandardEdition(true);
    $ldapService = App::make('App\Services\LdapService');
    $log['url'] = $this->getUrl($this->task->resourceable_type, $this->task->string_resourceable_id);
    $log['action'] = $this->getActionName($this->action);
    $log['resource_name'] = $this->getResourceName($this->task->resourceable);
    $log['user'] = $ldapService->getUserByUsername($this->user)->getDisplayName();

    return $log;
}
```

I can call this method from a Log instance, for example: `$log->getData()` but is it possible to call it from a query builder ?
If not, I have to loop on my query result to format each one of them.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to convert your log to this, you can use it by overriding the toArray function of your model :

```
public function toArray(): array
{
    Game::setWithoutStandardEdition(true);
    $ldapService = App::make('App\Services\LdapService');
    $log['url'] = $this->getUrl($this->task->resourceable_type, $this->task->string_resourceable_id);
    $log['action'] = $this->getActionName($this->action);
    $log['resource_name'] = $this->getResourceName($this->task->resourceable);
    $log['user'] = $ldapService->getUserByUsername($this->user)->getDisplayName();

    return $log;
}
```

then if you have an instance of log, you can do this :

```
$log->toArray();
```

or when having a FHINotification collection :

```
$FHINotification_collection->toArray();
```

Then your logs will be cast as an array using your custom toArray() function

if you want to access your attribute from your object, and not casting it to an array, then you should use accessor :

```
public function getUrlAttribute()
{
    Game::setWithoutStandardEdition(true);
    $ldapService = App::make('App\Services\LdapService');
    return $this->getUrl($this->task->resourceable_type, $this->task->string_resourceable_id);
}
```

and so on for each of your attribute

then you can use it doing so :

`$log->url`